# Support for Open ID Financial API (FAPI)

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect

Does Identity Server 4 support the Open ID Financial API (http://openid.net/wg/fapi/). If the answer is no, are there any plans to include support for the FAPI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We do support the read mode spec - see here

https://leastprivilege.com/2017/05/02/financial-apis-and-identityserver/

If you are interested in using IS in FAPI scenarios. Start a conversation with us via

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/intro/support.html